# Git multiple directories not in path

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to add and commit my dot files to a git repo, so I need to have multiple IDE/git/vim settings into the same repo but links don't work because I need to import the settings onto my work IDE.

I am going to make repos for each folder and use submodules to keep track of each project? That seems time intensive, is there an easy way to commit the files?

Edit: Flow chart:

| Local files | Repo |
| --- | --- |
| /IDE/settings/ | dot files |
| /.vimrc | dot files |
| /.gitconfig | dot files |

Comment: Why do the dot file repos need to know about the projects?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do, perhaps with an example? I'm struggling to understand the connection between a) dot files; b) multiple settings in the same repo; and c) submodules. What exactly do all these different directories and repos contain, and how do they need to relate to each other?

Comment: Could maybe look into GNU Stow or similar project for managing configuration in a single directory

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: It seems a lot simpler to have ~/.vimrc and ~/.gitconfig, etc. be symbolic links into a repo.  And in that repo maintain a script to build the necessary links when you go to a new box.